# Use the patience algorithm with gitk

Tags: configuration, git-diff, gitk

I like to view my commit history using gitk: it's simple, it's bundled with git, and it's fast.

However, it seems that gitk does not view diffs according to the algorighm specified in my git global configuration. Is there a way to make it do so (perhaps by leveraging the "external tool" configuration option available)?

I've made a simple example file:

```
void bye(void)
{
    printf("goodbye");
}

void hello(void)
{
    printf("Hello");
}
```

which is changed to:

```
void hello(void)
{
    printf("Hello");
}

void bye(void)
{
    printf("goodbye");
}
```

Gitk seems to always show line changes rather than the entire function block moving as patience suggests.